# How to use two near-identical classes that do not share the same parent class?

Tags: java, class, oop, code-duplication

I have 2 near-identical classes that ideally **should share the same parent class but don't** (because they come from separate libraries whose source code I cannot change).

To illustrate in an example, I have two classes like:

```
public class Cat {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }

    public CatFood findFood() {
        return new CatFood();
    }

    public void eat(CatFood food) {
        System.out.println("[Cat] Yum yum");
    }
}

public class Dog {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }

    public DogFood findFood() {
        return new DogFood();
    }

    public void eat(DogFood food) {
        System.out.println("[Dog] Yum yum");
    }
}
```

Now ideally I want to do something like:

```
Animal[] animals = {new Cat(), new Dog()};
for (Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.speak();
    animal.eat(animal.findFood());
}
```

but **`Cat` and `Dog` don't inherit from `Animal`** and I can't change their source code. I would also like to avoid relying on `instanceof` as a crutch:

```
for (Object animal : animals) {

    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
        dog.speak();
        dog.eat(dog.findFood());

    } else if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        Cat cat = (Cat) animal;
        cat.speak();
        cat.eat(cat.findFood());

    } else if (animal instanceof Rabbit) { // etc etc
}
```

The code just gets duplicated a zillion times, so if I make a small change to the logic I have to copy and paste a zillion times also.

So how can I use these classes with minimal code duplication?

Comment: An alternative to achive this is : Mycat extends Cat implements Animal , MyDog extends dog implements Animal , and Animal interface should have the three methods

Comment: Maybe you are interested in Adapter Pattern. Create your own interface and two classes implementing it and wrapping Cat and Dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Adapter pattern, but you need to implement a concrete Adapter for every type of animal:

```
interface Animal {
    void speak();
    void eat();
}

class DogAdapter implements Animal {
    private Dog dog;

    public DogAdapter(Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
    }

    public void speak() {
        dog.speak();
    }

    public void eat() {
        dog.eat(dog.findFood());
    }
}

class CatAdapter implements Animal {
    private Cat cat;

    public CatAdapter(Cat cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    public void speak() {
        cat.speak();
    }

    public void eat() {
        cat.eat(cat.findFood());
    }
}
```

And using a factory might encapsulate the concrete creation:

```
class AnimalFactory {
    public static Animal createAdapter(Dog dog) {
        return new DogAdapter(dog);
    }

    public static Animal createAdapter(Cat cat) {
        return new CatAdapter(cat);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Adapter and run in a loop:

```
Animal[] animals = {AnimalFactory.createAdapter(cat), AnimalFactory.createAdapter(dog)};

for (Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.speak();
    animal.eat();
}
```

One painpoint is the method `eat()` because the DogFood, CatFood, ... also has no common super type.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify these classes and you want to keep the code at its minimum you can use reflection to call these methods.
Something like:

```
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("speak");
method.invoke(obj);
```

But consider using reflection as a last resort only